# TextView in an ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Since i'm new here i was wondering how could i add a `TextView` in the `ActionBar`

It should be shown in the right corner of the action bar. 
The text for example is "Tell a friend"

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You just usethis function in your activity you can use the **Custom layout for** Activity...

```
 sActionBar = getActionBar();                   
 TabActivityPacs.sActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
 TabActivityPacs.sActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
 TabActivityPacs.sActionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
 final ViewGroup actionBarLayout = (ViewGroup) getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                                R.layout.custom_title,
                                null);
 TabActivityPacs.sActionBar.setCustomView(actionBarLayout);
```

You can design watever you want in the Custom title layout

All the best..

Answer (score 0):

First create a `layout.xml` file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tell_a_friend"        
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Tell a Friend"
/> 
</LinearLayout>
```

then in `menu.xml` write :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/tell_a_friend"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
    android:actionLayout="@layout/layout"
/>
</menu>
```

then in `Activity` :

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

   return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

then in `onOptionsItemSelected()` :

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected (MenueItem item){
switch (item.getItemId()){
         case R.id.tell_a_friend:
         Toast.makeText(this, "Tell a friend", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         break;
   }
   return true}
```

hope this may work for you..